# what is wrong with this code? Trying to display copied line of character array

Tags: c

I am just simply trying to copy entered line and display it on the screen But still, output includes some additional term.... What is wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

void copy(char to[], char from[]);

main()
{
    int length;
    int limit;
    char saved[MAXLINE];
    char len[MAXLINE];

    copy(saved,len);

    printf("%s", saved);
}

void copy(char to[],char from[])
{
    int a,i,c;

    i = 0;
    a = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        from[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    while((to[a] = from[a]) != EOF)
        ++a;
}
```

Comment: 1) `while((to[a] = from[a]) != EOF)` : `from[a]` doesn't include  `EOF`.

Comment: a) you did not nul-terminate the string b) EOF did not find its way into `from[]`.

Comment: 2) `printf("%s", saved);` : `%s` requests a C-String (end with NUL character).

Comment: @WeatherVane if the first `while` fails then for the first next `while` will copy un-initialized values from `from` to `to`. Am I right?

Comment: @duong_dajgja because OP did not nul terminate the string, or test for it, as already commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `printf()` is expecting a null-terminated string, yet the `copy()` function is not providing one.

Change the first loop in `copy()` so that the array index `i` is checked, to avoid buffer overflow, and then add a null-terminator after the loop terminates:

```
// check array index
while(i < MAXLINE-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    from[i] = c;
    ++i;
}

// add null-terminator to from[]
from[i] = '\0';
```

Then change the second loop so that it terminates when the null-terminator is encountered, and add a `\0` character to the end of `to[]`:

```
// change loop termination condition
while((to[a] = from[a]) != '\0')
    ++a;

// add null-terminator to to[]
to[a] = '\0';
```

Better, use the saved value of `i` to terminate the loop, and copy the `\0` from `from[]` to `to[]`:

```
// better, use i to terminate loop
for (a = 0; a <= i; a++)
    to[a] = from[a];
```

In my first version of the above loop, I inadvertently used `for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {}`, caught by @alk. This loop fails to copy the final `\0` character, since when `a == i`, the loop terminates without executing the body. The quick fix above, changing `a < i` to `a <= i` works, but the loop is no longer idiomatic (hence my initial trouble; I write `a < i` in loops by reflex). A possibly better solution would be to increment `i` after the `\0` character is stored in `from[]`, just as has been done for every other character in `from[]`. This is illustrated in the final code below.

Additionally, note that the function signature for `main()` should be `int main(void)`, and since `copy()` is declared as returning `void`, there should be no value `return`ed at the end of the function. And, to be truly correct, the types of array indices should be `size_t`, which is an `unsigned` integer type guaranteed to be able to hold any array index.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void)
{
//    int length;
//    int limit;
    char saved[MAXLINE];
    char len[MAXLINE];

    copy(saved,len);

    printf("%s", saved);

    return 0;
}

void copy(char to[],char from[])
{
    size_t a,i;
    int c;

    i = 0;
    a = 0;

    // check array index
    while(i < MAXLINE-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        from[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    // add null-terminator to from[], increment i
    from[i] = '\0';
    ++i;

    // use i to terminate copy loop
    for (a = 0; a < i; a++)
        to[a] = from[a];
}
```

Comment: And well,`i` and `a`  should better be `size_t` not `int`; `length` and `limit` aren't used.

Comment: Why can't I add null terminator as EOF?
eg at the end of from[i]? 

I know string requires '\0' character at the end but since I am not going to be printing from can't I put EOF value at the end?

Comment: @pluto20010-- not sure that I follow you. 1) If you don't place a null terminator at the end of `from[]`, it isn't a string; 2) result of `copy()` function should be the same as the input, i.e., if `to` is a string, then `from` is a string. You could write `copy()` to copy character arrays, which may or may not be strings; 3) `from` is an array of `char`, yet the value of `EOF` can't be represented by a `char`-- an array of `int` would be needed instead if you want to store this value; 4) `EOF` is not a character, but the value returned by IO functions when end of file is somehow signalled.